# Missing Dependency: python-chardet is needed by package reconfigure-0.1.50-1.noarch (ajenti)

Tags: centos, yum, dependencies, ajenti

I'm getting this error while installing ajenti.

```
yum install ajenti

Error: Missing Dependency: python-chardet is needed by 
package reconfigure-0.1.50-1.noarch (ajenti)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same error and found the solution. It seems happens because EPEL repo is not properly added on your system.

1. First, check the version of your operating system (CentOS 6.x/5.x? 32-bit/64-bit):

   `cat /etc/*-release`
2. Next, add the repo using these few lines:

   **CentOS 5.x:**

   ```
   wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
   wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
   sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-5*.rpm epel-release-5*.rpm
   ```

   **CentOS 6.x:**

   ```
   wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
   wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
   sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
   ```
3. Now enable remi:

   ```
   vim /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
   ```

   In `[remi]` change `enable=0` to `enable=1`.
4. Now type command `yum install ajenti` and it should succeed.

For more detail see [here](http://www.servermom.org/install-ajenti-cp/1457/).

Comment: I have followed same steps. It works only on Centos 6 not working in Centos 5.